# What is encrypting data at rest in database means?

Tags: database, encryption, amazon-rds

Does it mean that

1. the storage volume on which database is stored is encrypted
2. or each column of the database is encrypted by database automatically

Comment: It depends on the database provider (Postgres, MSSQL, Oracle) and the level and implementation of encryption (there are many possibles ways to encrypt everything from a column all the way to the database file). You will have to edit your answer and provide exactly what you want to know and the database service you want to know about.

Comment: Hi Igor thanks. AWS RDS just mentioned this term & hence I wasn't clear about it. I have put an email to them to explain the concept.

Answer (score 1):

Encrypt at rest refers to data being encrypted when it's stored (at rest), as opposed to encryption during transportation (not at rest) e.g. as seen with SSL/TLS.

You can not by the statement "encrypting data at rest in database", deduct if this is done by 1. or 2. or something else.